# How to search an array and store its parent.

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

excuse me if my terminology is off a little here. Using a rest api is a little new to me.

I have two websites and a function that works as follows:

Website A:
Makes a reques to website B to find out if the URL exists within the Rest API Resutls.

```
//Get the websites URL (websiteA.com
$url = get_site_url();      

//Get the content from websiteB api     
$content = file_get_contents('websiteB.com/wp-json/wp/v2/websites-api');

//Decode the result
$decode = json_decode($content);

//This is whats returned. This is not the complete array but shows
//what Im looking to do
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1040
        [date] => 2018-07-04T09:15:17
        [date_gmt] => 2018-07-04T08:15:17
        [guid] => stdClass Object (
         [rendered] => http://websiteA.com
        )            
        [link] => http://websiteA.com
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1040
        [date] => 2018-07-04T09:15:17
        [date_gmt] => 2018-07-04T08:15:17
        [guid] => stdClass Object (
         [rendered] => http://websiteC.com
        )            
        [link] => http://websiteC.com
    )
)
```

I need to find out how to search this array for the link matching the $url and save the parent object as an seperate array to echo parts out into different functions.

Ive tried the following:

```
if (in_array($url, $decode)) {
    echo 'its in there';
} else {
    echo 'its not';
}
```

I get 'its not' every time, even though I can see it in there.

Comment: are you comparing to link or rendered key???

Comment: You can't use in_array() as by definition the function checks if a value exists in an array. Your $url will likely be a string, while your $decode contains objects. That is why when the method is used, it always echoes "its not" as the function is comparing object to a string. As Lovepreet Singh mentioned, you will have to transverse the array, access the objects at each iteration and look for a match.

Answer (score 1):

Need to traverse through `$decode` array and then match with url properties `guid->rendered & link`. Code should be like:

```
$found = false;
foreach ($decode as $value) {
    if ($value->guid->rendered == $url || $value->link == $url) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($found) {
    echo 'its in there';
} else {
    echo 'its not';
}
```

**UPDATE:** To find url exists in a given object or not.

```
function foundUrl($decode) {
    foreach ($decode as $value) {
        if (is_object($value) || is_array($value)) {
            foundUrl($value);
        } else if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN)) {
            throw new Exception("Found");
        }
    }
}

$found = false;
try {
    foundUrl($decode);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $found = true;
}

if ($found) {
    echo 'its in there';
} else {
    echo 'its not';
}
```

Comment: A clean answer. I was writing this as well but you beat me to it. =)

Comment: Hi, this has got me on the right path, got it workinghowever, I still need to get that single array from the list of arrays to use in other functions. How can I save that one array as another array?

Comment: Do you want array of urls in `$decode` array? If yes, which one `rendered` or `link` or both?

Comment: There's lots of other parts to each object I need to send to my functions. So i need to be able to find the object containing the url and use that object in other places. Almost like save that particular object as a variable.

Comment: To how much levels these objects are nested?

Comment: No further than [rendered]

Comment: So you need all URL in this object or object name which contains urls?

Comment: If im looking for websiteA.com then I need the whole containing object so I can take different parts of that object and pass them to different functions.